# I get a failed to load resource error when using jquery $ .post on a web server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, post

PHP $ .post controller as follows

```
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');

define('CONFIG' ,__DIR__ . '/../classes/config.php');

foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/../classes/*.php') as $className){
    require $className;
}

require __DIR__ . '/../helper.php';
if (isset ($_POST['p'])) {
    session_start ();
    $Process = $_POST ['p'];
    if ($process == 'atp') {
        $id = $_POST[ 'id'];
        atp(base64_decode_url($ id));
    }
}

function atp($id){
    include CONFIG;
    $product=$db->query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_id = "' . $id .'"',PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)->fetch();
    $res=Page::GetFirstImageById($id);
    $resim='./da-webmaster/public/img/'.$res[0]['ResimAd'];
    if(session('login')!=""){
        if(session('user_type')==1&&session("admin_confirm")){
            if($product['camp_active']==1&&session("user_type")==1){
                $price=$product['saler_price'];
            }else{
                $price=$product['saler_price'];
            }
            $qty=$product['saler_qty'];
        }else{
            if($product['camp_active']==1){
                $price=$product['prod_camp_price'];}
            else{
                $price=$product['prod_price'];
            }
            $qty=1;
        }
        if(true){
            $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO baskets SET basket_kid =? ,prod_id =? ,prod_qty =? ,basket_kip=? ,prod_price=?,prod_name=?,total_price=?,prod_thumbnail_path=?');
            $insert = $query->execute([
         session('id'),$id,$qty,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$price,$product['prod_name'],($price*$qty),$resim]);
        }else{}
    }else{
        if(isset($_SESSION["shopcart"])){
            $shopcart=$_SESSION["shopcart"];
            $products=$shopcart["products"];
        }
            //session içinde product yoksa
        else{
            $products=array();
        }
        if(array_key_exists($product['prod_id'],$products)){
        }else{
            $products[$product['prod_id']]=$product;
            $_SESSION["shopcart"]["products"]=$products;
        }
    }
    totalhesap();
}
```

My jquery code is as follows

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add-to-cart-btn').click(function(){
    var url="controller/ajax.php";
    var data={
      p:"atp",
      id:$(this).attr("id")
    }
    $.post(url,data,function(response){
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

The purpose of my code in the index.php file, click the add-to-cart-btn button to receive the id and send the function to my user session or database according to the state to add products. My code is on the server while running wampserver localhost

> failed to load resource: the server responded controller / ajax.php: 1 with a status of 500

and I get

> net :: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED: controller / ajax.php: 1

Comment: 500 normally means a catestrophic PHP error, in the PHP code os course

Comment: It's indicating an error in your php - what happens when you debug/step through?

Comment: Did you check the PHP Error log for any clues

Comment: What on earth is the point of a `if(true){` with an empty else. Surely that means run this and as such is just a waste of code

Comment: **Warning:** `WHERE prod_id = "' . $id .'"'` ...this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / PDO. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Where he took me in my error log.      
foreach($_SESSION["shopcart"]["products"] as $product){
        $res=Page::GetFirstImageById($product['prod_id']);
        $resim='./da-webmaster/public/img/'.$res[0]['ResimAd'];

Comment: Ok. And what is the exact error message in your log? We can't guess it...

Comment: My exact error log is as follows
 PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/mz0x4zp42nl4/public_html/controller/ajax.php on line 248
My class function that caused the error is below
    public static function GetFirstImageById($id){ 
    include CONFIG; 
    $resim = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `resimler` WHERE UrunId = ? 
    LIMIT 1"); 
    $resim->execute([ $id ]); 
    $resimler = $resim->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    return $resimler; }

Comment: @RamazanKırmızıgün please use the "edit" button (just under the little blue "php" and "jquery" tags) to add code and error information to your question. It does not belong in the comments, this is not like a discussion forum. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. exactly one of those lines is 248?